# Require type parameter to be a struct

Tags: rust

I have a function that I've specified a type parameter `T` on, which I assume to be a struct. I then collect an iterator of `T` into a Vec.:

```
pub fn get_matches<T>(
    &self,
) -> Vec< T> 
{
    ...
    some_iter.
        .map(|(k, _v)| T{key:(**k).to_string(), hits: 0})
        .collect()
}
```

I get [this error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0574):

```
96 |             .map(|(k, _v)| T{key:(**k).to_string(), hits: 0})
   |                            ^ not a struct, variant or union type
```

I've tried having the return type be a type parameter, but I can't work out how to get the `Vec`'s element type and instantiate that either. I just want to produce elements of a certain shape (that is with a `key: string`, and `hits: usize`) and return a container of whatever the caller is expecting.

Comment: You are accepting `T` of any type. How can you be certain that `T` will have the fields (and only those fields): `key` and `hits`?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to specify. Alternatively I'm happy to have -> T, and do something like `T::ElemType{key: , hits :}` but I can't work out how to specify that either. (and I expect then I have to put constraints on T::ElemType instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust generics are different from C++ templates. There are valid reasons why they are different, such as better error reporting and faster compilation.

In C++, template (if we oversimplify) types are not checked at the initial invocation stage, rather the template continues to expand until it is either successful, or runs into an operation that is not supported by that specific type.

While in Rust, types are checked immediately. The specification must be given up-front, which means that any error is caught at the call site, as opposed to deep in a template expansion.

Your specific example assumes that every `T` should have fields `key` and `hits`, but `T` can be anything starting from primitive types to non-public structs that don't have `key` or `hits` fields.

The Rust way of doing things is to declare a trait and use it to specify that the type has certain constructor function for you. In this context the trait will be a zero-cost abstraction, because of static polymorphism.

```
trait StringConstructable {
    fn new(string: String) -> Self;
}

struct Test {
    key: String,
    hits: usize
}

impl StringConstructable for Test {
    fn new(string: String) -> Self {
        Test {
            key: string,
            hits: 0
        }
    }
}

fn test<T: StringConstructable>() -> T {
    T::new("test".to_string())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0ec2cca8c148fb8aec2f2da534674c3)

Or implement and require `From<String>` for your `T`.

```
struct Test {
    key: String,
    hits: usize
}

impl From<String> for Test {
    fn from(string: String) -> Test {
        Test {
            key: string,
            hits: 0
        }
    }
}

fn test<T: From<String>>() -> T {
    T::from("test".to_string())
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=671eea3ff9fdb9b9374eccf1ca74e9bc)

Comment: The [Bounds chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html) from the Rust Book. *When working with generics, the type parameters often must use traits as bounds to stipulate what functionality a type implements*. Good answer. You could explain the way that Rust checks the "specifications up-front" is through the use of trait bounds